# Read From File Word For Word and Determining New Lines C++

Tags: c++, string, file, newline

I have a project where I am supposed to read in words from a text file and store them alphabetically in a binary search tree. I am reading in the words into a string, so I guess you could say I am going string by string. I do not want to read char by char, or by using getline to obtain an entire line at a time. I just want to go word by word. I am supposed to be able to store what line each word appears on and I can't figure out how to read word by word and also figure out where each new line starts. Hope someone can help!

Comment: Try `std::stringstream` to read word by word and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a word skips leading whitespace, and a newline is considered whitespace. You need to change your approach.

You can write your own function to skip leading whitespace and call it before you read each word. Just have it return the number of newlines it found so you can increment the line number.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to read char by char, or by using getline to obtain an entire line at a time.

Might I recommend anyway... use `getline()`! This makes line numbering far simpler for your algorithm, and doesn't prohibit you from using the << operator to go word by word. Once you have a `std::string`, you can use the `std::stringstream` to extract each word, knowing in advance what the line number is by using an incrementing integer on each call to `getline()`. Remember to check the stream after each extraction to ensure it has more data.

I'd have commented instead if I had the rep. What have you tried so far?